# wordpress Mobile Menu not hidden after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I made a one-page design with some links.

When I browse the site on my smartphone, open the main menu with the button and click on a link (which scrolls to the same page), the mobile menu isn’t hidden but placed on the right site of the content.

this is link http://www.sarahspancakecafe.com.sg/

How to fix that?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu-item-object-custom a').click(function(){ 
        $('.navbar-header button').click();
    });
});
```

I tried it on your site and it seemed to work well.

Comment: where  to put this code?

Comment: I would put this code in an external JS file or embed it in your HTML

Comment: this code have a syntax error can you check it please                                              thanks you                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               $(document).ready(function(){\
    $('.menu-item-object-custom a').click(function(){ 
        $('.navbar-header button').click();
    });
});

Comment: here the my theme .js                                                                                                      <br/>                                                                                                                          http://www.sarahspancakecafe.com.sg/wp-content/themes/kataleya/js/theme.js

Comment: You should be able to put the supplied JS at the end of that file. Make sure JQuery is included and that should hide the menu when an item is clicked. There was a typo. It's fixed now.

Comment: Just verified it myself. Nice site by the way.

Comment: it's working, thank you so much....

Comment: Glad I could help!