# Remove open class, on mobile navigation with jquery when anchor link is clicked

Tags: menu, anchor

i read a lot of similar topics and created a code that is suppose when i click on a button with class - __mPS2id - to remove "opened" in my open menu with class "menu_mobile" but i dont work. Can someone say what is wrong?

```
jQuery('.__mPS2id').on('click', function(e) {
        $('.menu_mobile').removeClass('opened');
    
    });
```

My html is

```
<div class="menu_mobile scheme_dark opened">
    <div class="menu_mobile_inner">
        <a class="menu_mobile_close icon-cancel"></a> 


<nav class="menu_mobile_nav_area">
<ul id="menu_mobile" class="menu_mobile_nav">
<li id="menu_mobile-item-1291" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1291"><a href="#home" data-ps2id-api="true" class="__mPS2id _mPS2id-h mPS2id-highlight"><span>Начало</span></a></li>

<li id="menu_mobile-item-1545" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1545"><a href="#uslugi" data-ps2id-api="true" class="__mPS2id _mPS2id-h mPS2id-clicked"><span>Профиль услуг</span></a></li>

<li id="menu_mobile-item-1539" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1539"><a href="#photos" data-ps2id-api="true" class="__mPS2id _mPS2id-h"><span>Готовые проекты</span></a></li>

</ul></nav>
```

Comment: I also tried to use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433781/wordpress-mobile-menu-not-hidden-after-click 

And put - `code` $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.__mPS2id a').click(function(){ 
        $('.menu_mobile_close button').click();
    });
});  
`code`
But it dont work too :(

Answer (score 0):

i found 2 solutions! Installed Custom JavaScript plugin and created those 2 codes, both work

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.menu-item-object-custom').on('click touchend', function() {
 $('.menu_mobile').removeClass('opened');
    });
});
```

and

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.__mPS2id').on('click touchend', function() {
$("a.menu_mobile_close").trigger('click');
    });
});
```